# Auto back-indent word 'else' in if/else statement in Vim

Tags: plugin-system

There is this feature or module in Vim which auto back-indents words during writing if/else statements. For example:

```
if a == 1:
   xx   <-- here when I press enter cursor goes right below end of word "xx".
else   <-- however as soon as I fully type word "else" this line gets automatically indented backwards
```

What module/feature allows this auto-back-indent when typing word 'else'? As in, how do I enable this functionality?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning. There are quite a few (local to buffer) options in Vim to work with indenting.

`autoindent` is the most basic setting; it simply makes a new line to have an equivalent number (influenced by `copyindent` and `preserveindent` options) of leading spaces/tabs as in a previous line;

`smartindent` is a "lightweight" thing for a C-like language. It indents/unindents braces and hashes, and also *indents* after a few keywords, such as "if", "while" etc. (See `:h 'cinwords'`) But it lacks an *unindent* for keywords, such as "else";

`cindent` option (and the corresponding VimScript function `cindent()`) is a full-featured builtin C/C++ indenter; it's also used as a fallback by many C-like languages, such as Java, Rust and so on; however, it's of a little use for Python and such;

also, there's a builtin indenter for LISP language, but it's probably of a little interest now;

`indentexpr` is the most flexible option; it could be set to a VimScript expression (normally, a function call) to be evaluated in runtime;

So, as one may guess, for almost all programming languages Vim computes indents by re-evaluating an expression stored in `indentexpr`. But, of course, an ordinary vimmer doesn't want to implement `function GetPythonIndent()` himself, so it's written as a part of standard plugin shipped with Vim.

The core Vim command to enable this functionality is `:h filetype`. If entered without arguments, it prints the current state:

```
:filetype<CR>
filetype detection:ON plugin:ON indent:ON
```

So there are (at least) three subsystems designed to work together: filetype detection, filetype settings and indent settings. But let's focus only on `indent`. Concerning `ftdetect` it's enough to say that the file type must be somehow detected before a relevant indent subplugin can do its job.

So, if `indent:ON` then Vim simply sources `$VIMRUNTIME/indent.vim` which sets a trap for all subsequent `FileType` events (see `:h :autocmd`). Then if we got some `x.y.z` filetype the code in `indent.vim` sources all `indent/x.vim`, `indent/y.vim` and `indent/z.vim` found on `:h 'runtimepath'`. A standard implementation for `setlocal indentexpr=GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)` is then found in `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/python.vim`

In `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` (note: Vim8+ only) there's a line `filetype plugin indent on`, so if you source the recommended defaults for Vim (e.g. `runtime defaults.vim` on top of your vimrc), then you don't have to enable ftplugin functionality manually. In Neovim, `filetype plugin indent on` is a builtin default setting.

Comment: +1 Amazing how you (and several others in **this** community) are willing and able to turn the answer to a question into an extensive tutorial. Thx a ton :-))

Comment: Thanks for this explicit answer. Nonetheless, perhaps i missed it, but how do i enable such feature? (that was my initial question).

Comment: @guntbert Well, I'm rather a lazy person who hates writing long texts in a foreign language, but for this particular case, I believe, such deep inside is very essential. There's at least a couple of new questions and/or problems arising every week in this site that directly connected to ftplugin and stuff.

Comment: @user1880405 Normally, it should work out-of-the-box. Try entering `:filetype` and see the output. If it's off, read the answer carefully and try to find out how that came the plugins are switched off in your setup.

Comment: @Matt IKR? This is a topic for which it seems a short answer is rarely possible or appropriate...kudos for taking this one on.:) I confess that I've surrendered to my lazy gene a time or two in the past as it compelled me to steer clear of such questions. ;)

Answer (score 2):

@Matt has already given a correct (and good) answer, but here's answer from someone who is old enough to have learned to love vi in it's original form, without fancy bits. I keep boring people stiff with this subject, so beware.

Indentation discipline is, of course, a really good idea, as it helps the eye see how the code is structured, logically. And it is mildly annoying that you have to use ^D to 'outdent' (?) - 'backdent' (?) - whatever the word may be, so my solution has been to simply do what some of the early IDEs later adopted: write the end-of-block marker as soon as you write the start of the block - so, when you write '{' in C, you write '}' on the next line, at the same indentation, when you write 'then' in ksh, you immediately add a 'fi;' on the next line, etc. That way, don't forget to close your blocks, and the indentation works coveniently as well.