# What option controls how much space is added after a new line?

Tags: indentation, whitespace, filetype-markdown

When I set `tw` vim will auto wrap lines at `tw`. When breaking that line vim usually places some spaces to keep the indentation of the previous line. Example

```
foo
  bar<suppose that a wrap happens here>
  tar
## <- this amount of space is added to keep the line idented
```

What are the options that control this behavior?

-- edit

To be more precise I was editing markdown and it indents lists this way

```
- foo bar tar <wrap happens!>
    tick tack
```

While I expect

```
- foo bar tar <wrap happens!>
  tick tack
```

I just don't want to tie the response to markdown so that I can apply it to other formats.

Comment: Quite a few: autoindent, smartindent, cindent, indentexpr. Also not to forget copyindent, expandtab and shiftwidth. You may want to look at [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/23135/auto-back-indent-word-else-in-if-else-statement-in-vim). If something is still unclear, please, make your question more specific.

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: When you edit a markdown file... Do you have indentexpr set? What does `:set indentexpr?` say when you're editing a markdown file... (Wondering if you have a plug-in such as vim-polyglot or vim-markdown or similar installed that might have a particular indent setting for markdown...) In particular, I can't reproduce your indentation issue, maybe try with `vim -u NONE -N`, then open a markdown file, see if you get the same behavior or not.

Comment: @filbranden yeah is something in my vimrc, it can be found here https://github.com/dhilst/dhilst/blob/master/.vimrc. I'm using neovim v0.4.3 on mac.

Comment: The loaded scripts: https://gist.github.com/dhilst/470f9431e45320ba08f6d31294156357

Comment: Was precisely vim-polyglot, I will look at their source to see if I can find what is wrong, a big thanks!

Comment: I think I found. My problem is that I `set ts=2 sts=2 sw=2` on my `.vimrc` but `vim-markdown` (pulled by `vim-poliglot` uses 4 as default: vim-markdown automatically insert the indent. By default, the number of spaces of indent is 4. If you'd like to change the number as 2, just write: vim-markdown automatically insert the indent. By default, the number of spaces of indent is 4. If you'd like to change the number as 2, just write:

Comment: Yeah was exactly that, thanks Matt and filbranden, this solved my problem `let g:vim_markdown_new_list_item_indent = 2 `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are too many such options to be able to answer this quesion in a general manner. However, they are mostly programming-languages oriented or exotic ones.

In case of a "text document", such as markdown, you likely have to deal with only `autoindent` (an alternative is `smartindent`, as `si` is sometimes set default in some vimrc's, but `si` is a sort of "universal programming language" indenter, and you should better keep it off for markdown and such). Also note that `autoindent` is off by default, so you probably have `set ai` in your vimrc.

There are also several options which influence number / structure of tabs / spaces in an (auto-)indent, but, I guess, it's not the point of your interest right now.

Also speaking of markdown, it's worth to note that there's `formatlistpat` option (set by ftplugin) to detect "lists". So "the list items" in markdown will get indented even if `set noautoindent`.

And the last but not least, `autoindent` will come in play if you have `textwidth` set. Not `wrap` and `wrapmargin`. The point is that `textwidth` results in adding "real" newlines in your file (and hence `autoindent` will do its job). While `wrapmargin` results in "on-screen" wrapping.

Comment: I have this setting `set ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 et` on my .vimrc. Also, I don't know why I have ai set. I note that when I press O I got the same behavior, so I think is `ai` related

Comment: @geckos `I don't know why I have ai set` Just do `:verbose set ai?`

Comment: Nice trick,         Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vim-polyglot/indent/markdown.vim line 8

Comment: Removing vim-polyglot fixed :D Thanks!