# How to configure what happens after hitting enter inside parentheses

Tags: indentation

`|` - cursor position

when I edit JavaScript file:

`function(|)`

pressing "Enter" gives

```
function(
  |
)
```

Which is good for me. But when I edit R file it gives:

```
function(
         |
)
```

How can I configure what happens after hitting enter inside parentheses for specific language?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/23135/auto-back-indent-word-else-in-if-else-statement-in-vim

Comment: Also `:h ft-r-indent`, `:h 'cinoptions'`, `:h cinoptions-values` and such.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @Matt thank you so much!